# Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espressgit so-core:3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

Hours ago the gradle sync works well, however a moment ago, the testing dependency failed to download

Could not GET 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/com/android/support/test/espresso/espressgit%20so-core/3.0.1/espressgit%20so-core-3.0.1.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict

```
{
   errors: [
   {
   status: 409,
   message: "The repository 'oss-snapshot-local' rejected the resolution of an artifact 'oss-snapshot-local:com/android/support/test/espresso/espressgit so-core/3.0.1/espressgit so-core-3.0.1.pom' due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy."
   } ]
}
```

Deleted them solved the issue but I would like to retain the espresso dependency.

```
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espressgit so-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you typed `git s` or `sgit` into your build script while you thought the focus is in your terminal.

Look closely at the dependency, it says `espressgit so-core` but should probably be `espresso-core` which would then resolve from the android support repository and not reach the jfrog repository which responds with 409 whyever.